# weird behavior when receiving push notifications

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

So I followed Parse's guide on setting up push notifications yesterday. I left the client channel to "" for Broadcast. And when I tried to send notifications, My phone didn't receive any. After trying to trouble shoot for a while I gave up and went to bed.

Then I was waken up by my phone buzzing at 6 in the morning. I look at it and it's the dozen push notifications I sent like 8 hours earlier. (To be clear when I sent them I set the all to now. I didn't schedule them). So when I try to send them today it didn't work. I tried switching the channel and it worked. I sent a push notification and my phone received it instantly. After that I went to eat, came back and tried to test some things out and my phone doesn't receive them anymore.

Has anyone ever noticed behavior like this or know what the problem might be. Parse tells me that they send just fine and I don't know if it's an issue with my code because it CAN receive them.

Comment: I've noticed it. it sometimes duplicates them.

Comment: Do you know what might be causing the behavior

Comment: That I really don't know. so I just let it be for the moment as it seems it's within either their web service or sdk.